# MySQL ENUM column won't match quoted values after import to new machine

Tags: mysql

Recently I've imported a new database to develop on my local machine, however it doesn't work: the ENUM column only works when the variable is sent without quotation marks. Here's an example:

```
mysql.local>select count(*) from psh_products where active = 1;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    72782 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)

mysql.local>select count(*) from psh_products where active = '1';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

In case you're wondering about the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `psh_products` (
  `productID` int(12) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `main_sku` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `sku` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shortsku` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `upc` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `quantity` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `buy_now` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `seller_cost` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `cdate` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `codedir` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `basic_colorID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `manu_colorID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `brandID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `matID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sizeID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `size_sID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `styleID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `featID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `occID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `widthID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `width_sID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `genderID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `gender_sID` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `hits` int(2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `active` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `tags` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `tmp_img` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `imgact` enum('again','flip','resize','moderated','badimg','badimgm','badimga') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'moderated',
  `status` enum('new','moderated') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'moderated',
  `quanflag` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` enum('0','1') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`productID`),
  KEY `idx_cid` (`catID`),
  KEY `idx_bid` (`brandID`),
  KEY `idx_act` (`active`),
  KEY `idx_act_hits` (`active`,`hits`),
  KEY `idx_wid` (`widthID`),
  KEY `idx_sid` (`sizeID`),
  KEY `idx_styleid` (`styleID`),
  KEY `idx_sku` (`sku`),
  KEY `idx_msku` (`main_sku`),
  KEY `idx_matid` (`matID`),
  KEY `idx_cid_mstyleid` (`catID`,`featID`),
  KEY `idx_shortsku` (`shortsku`),
  KEY `idx_quant` (`quantity`),
  KEY `idx_quanflag` (`quanflag`),
  KEY `idx_hits` (`hits`),
  KEY `idx_act_qua_cat` (`active`,`quantity`,`catID`),
  KEY `idx_act_qua_cat_sho` (`active`,`quantity`,`catID`,`shortsku`),
  KEY `idx_bcolor_id` (`basic_colorID`),
  KEY `idx_mcolor_id` (`manu_colorID`),
  KEY `idx_cdate` (`cdate`),
  KEY `idx_deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `occID` (`occID`),
  KEY `idx_fid` (`featID`),
  KEY `width_sID` (`width_sID`,`genderID`,`gender_sID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=72790 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Any ideas are welcome!

Comment: What's the charset and collation of the connection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that when you use a numerical value in a query against an enum data type as in your first query, the numerical value is treated as an index, not as one of the enumerated values.

So, querying

```
select count(*) from psh_products where active = 1;
```

is really equivalent to

```
select count(*) from psh_products where active = '0';
```

since '0' is the first item (index 1) in the enumeration.

Because of this confusion, [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) explicilty states "we strongly recommend that you do not use numbers as enumeration values."

Answer (score 0):

That was my mistake, I did

```
UPDATE psh_products SET ACTIVE = 1 WHERE ......
```

So the update overwrote the `'1'`'s that were there with `1`'s.