# Removing duplicate results while using UNION SELECT

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Ive got a problem with a MySQL query.

Let's say, we have two tables:

### id    qty

1......1

2......1

3......1

4......3

and

### id    qty

1......2

2......1

6......1

7......2

What I actually need to get is a result filtered by id, so there are no duplicate id's. If they are two same id's, only id whith a higher qty number will be considered. So in and ideal situation I would get this result:

### id    qty

1......2

2......1

3......1

4......3

6......1

7......2

What Ive tried so far is a UNION SELECT, which works fine, but when it comes across a duplicate ID it wont remove duplicates, as it removes just duplicates rows. GROUP BY didnt help either. I could still sort this out through an array in PHP, but I would love having this sorted at MySQL level if possible.

Thanks everyone for you help, it's much appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> GROUP BY didnt help either

Really? Did you try like this?

```
SELECT id, MAX(qty) AS qty
FROM
(
    SELECT id, qty FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, qty FROM table2
) T1
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Actually I didnt. This looks quite promissing ;) Will give it a try. Thanks ;)

Comment: +1: Minor question on efficiency: Would you want to use a `UNION ALL` since the `GROUP BY` is going to roll everything up anyhow?

Comment: Wow. I learn something new every day and this works like a charm! I didn't know that I could use subqueries in this way (I tried, but it didn't work before as I forgot to use an alias (T1 in your example) for subselect query;)) Thank you mate!

Comment: @Ondrej: Regarding numeric ENUMs, see my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574760/mysql-enum-column-wont-match-quoted-values-after-import-to-new-machine/7574808#7574808).

Comment: Ah ok, another interesting thing, so I'll go for int instead. Thank you ;)

Comment: Solved my problem. very handy solution.

Answer (score 17):

You can use UNION DISTINCT. Maybe it runs...

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE ...

UNION DISTINCT

SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE ...
```

Comment: Note: DISTINCT is default option, so one simple UNION is sufficient :)  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html

Comment: `DISTINCT` is the default option, so you can use `UNION ALL` if you want to retrieve the duplicate ones too.