# Avoiding duplicates in mysql query that uses UNION and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have two tables, lets say table1 and table2 with common columns, id and update_date. I am looking to get the id's and update_date based on latest update_date in descending order. I have used 'union' and 'order by' together which gave the results in descending order of update_date but there are duplicate id's which I am not sure how to get rid of.

My query is like,

```
(select id,update_date from table1 where [condition])
UNION
(select id,update_date from table2 where [condition])
order by update_date desc;
```

I can just get rid of the duplicate id's by adding select distinct id from (above query) as temp; but the problem is that I need the update_date too.

Can anyone suggest how to get rid of duplicates and still get both id and update_date information.

Comment: I hope this following link may help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7640396/removing-duplicate-results-while-using-union-select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the latest update out of duplicates this one should work:

```
SELECT id, max(update_date) AS last_update
FROM
  ( (select id,update_date from table1 where [conditions])
     UNION
    (select id,update_date from table2 where [conditions]) ) both_tables
GROUP BY id
ORDER by last_update DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the max() suggestion. I changed the query to get rid of ambiguous column error. The modified version that worked for me is : 
select id, max(update_date) from ((select id,update_date from table1 where [condition]) UNION (select id,update_date from table2 where [condition]) order by update_date DESC) as temp group by id;

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the query in a `DISTINCT` block:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM (
  select id,update_date from table1 where [condition]
  UNION
  select id,update_date from table2 where [condition]
)
order by update_date desc;
```

Comment: Thanks. This did not work as update_date can be different in the two tables for the same id. So distinct is returning all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Limit the second query's results:

```
select id, update_date
  from table1
 where [conditions]
union
select id, update_date
  from table2
 where [conditions]
   and id not in (select id from table1 where [conditions])
```

Comment: The problem was that I have to get id and "latest" update_date. For example, the same id can have different update_date's in these two tables. So I have to get the latest update_date for that id in both tables.